# How can I catch missing or empty parameters passed into my Web API method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have this simple Net Core Web API HttpPut method to update an object called `BakeCookieRecipe`.

It works fine if the user passes in an `id` and `BakeCookieRecipe` object,

but if someone usint the API forgets to pass in the `id` and/or an empty `BakeCookieRecipe` object, the browser throws a 404 error.

I guess that's fine, but I also want to log the event with my logger.

But for some reason, I can't catch when the `id` and/or `BakeCookieRecipe` is either missing or empty.

Here is my code.  You can see where I am trying to test the `id` and `bakeCookieRecipe` object that is passed in and log it.

But it never does. It also never sends the `NotFound` message I define.

Is there anything I can change to help me?

Thanks!

```
HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutBakeCookieRecipe(string id, BakeCookieRecipe bakeCookieRecipe)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || id != bakeCookieRecipe.BakeId)
    {
        Message = "id is missing or not found";
        _logger.LogError(Message);
        return NotFound("Id missing.");
    }

    if (!IsGuid(bakeCookieRecipe.CookieRecipeId.ToString()) || bakeCookieRecipe.CookieRecipeId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        Message = "RecipeId is missing";
        _logger.LogWarning(Message);
        return NotFound("RecipeId is missing or not found.");
    }

    _context.Entry(bakeCookieRecipe).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return NoContent();
}

// test to make sure a value is a Guid
private bool IsGuid(string value)
{
    Guid x;
    return Guid.TryParse(value, out x);
}
```

Comment: Because the API created coudn't find a PutBakeCookieRecipe endpoint without the id parameter in signature, so it didn't hit your function, try adding a function without the id parameter signature that only logs or use optinal id parameter and check for null inside your code

Comment: @J.Salas Oh wow, I didn't know it couldn't even find my method! Wow, so I need to create a duplicate just like above, but have no id? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem causes  using a new "smart" feature of Net6 that demands that all properties should be marked as nullable. And probably you are using  API controller attribute. In this case an error is generated before in gets inside of the action. This is why you can't catch it.
So if you have problem only here you can change the action

```
HttpPut("{id?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutBakeCookieRecipe(string id, BakeCookieRecipe? bakeCookieRecipe)
```

search this site, especially my answers, how to to get rid of this error forever.

If you wanna cath the parameters values, just remove an [ApiController] attribute for testing

Comment: Thank you, so in your example code, are both `id` and `BakeCookieRecipe` nullable?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You are welcome! Yes, they are nullable by default, but for some reasons Net6 wants you to make them nullable explicitely

Answer (score 1):

> I can't catch when the id and/or BakeCookieRecipe is either missing or
> empty.

By default, you would get 400 error  directly without getting into the method In webapi projects

You could try remove the `ApiController` and `Route` attribute and remove the parameter in the constructor of `HttpPut` attribute

```
[HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutBakeCookieRecipe(string id, BakeCookieRecipe bakeCookieRecipe)
        {
            ........
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Resgit the route in middleware as below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "RouteName", pattern: "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can set your fields in the dto to [Required] and also use try catch to catch the error message .
Below is a simple code to this Hope this helps

DTO:

```
public class BakeCookieRecipe
{

    [Required]
    public Guid CookieRecipeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid BakeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BakeName { get; set;}
}
```

Put Method:

```
    [HttpPut("Bake")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid id, BakeCookieRecipe b)
    {
        try
        {
            var user  = await _context.bakeCookies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.CookieRecipeId == id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }user.BakeName = b.BakeName; ;
            user.BakeId = b.BakeId;
            user.CookieRecipeId= b.CookieRecipeId;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return NoContent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
            {

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
    }[![Here ive attached the image of the resulting webapi][1]][1]
```